# Disable Rotation of UIViewController in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I want to disable rotating only one viewController in my Application in iOS 8.
I try with some older methods but it is not working or deprecated in iOS 8.

I try this new method of Rotation in iOS 8.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

but i don't know how to disable the rotation in this method. I want only Landscape mode in this viewController. I checked other SO question but my code still not working in iOS 8.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 6):

Now this is easier. Try using:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Try with:   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

Comment: Eva's answer works for me.
But change to
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
to kill the warning message.

Comment: Worked on ViewController presented with presentViewController:animated