# How to disable rotation of specific view iOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, ios8, rotation

I would like to ask how to disable rotation of a specific view in iOS 8. Although there is an answer in: [Disable Rotation of UIViewController in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628338/disable-rotation-of-uiviewcontroller-in-ios-8)

However my app still crashes with error: 
*** Assertion failure in -[ARQuestionPageViewController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.69/UIPageViewController.m:996

even when this function is deprecated in iOS 8.

Could anyone help me how to do that? Thank you!